# Extract word from sentence with a dash and a unique number

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string with the word **MANDATE-ID-** followed by a ID. What I'm trying to achieve is extracting it from the sentence as string. The ID is always a number which can differ in length. What expression can I use for this?

---

My String:

*Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet MANDATE-ID-111 Reference: E2E-ID-0913286 Description: My Description*

Comment: no offence intended but this is a simple as asking "how do I match 1 to many digits?"

Comment: Damn.. thanks for the wakeup call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex pattern `(?<=MANDATE-ID-)\d+\b`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 0):

I'm stupid; /MANDATE-ID-(\d+)/